# Recommend a Rackspace Cloud Server API Language Binding?

Tags: cloud-computing, rackspace

Rackspace publishes only a hard-to-use HTTP and JSON/XML based "API" (they call it an API but it's really a non-standard Web Service without a WSDL).

There are dozens of open-source language bindings to choose from. I have tried three of them so far and they're all horrible (incomplete, buggy, and/or undocumented).

Can anybody recommend a language binding which is reasonably complete, well documented, and bug-free? I can use Perl, Python, PHP, or Java. My ultimate objective is to create a script/program that will provision a server, launch a process inside it, wait for the process to finish, copy the results to the local server, and destroy the remote server. What's the best choice for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at libcloud?  http://incubator.apache.org/libcloud/